# Performance of array reverse in ActionScript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, reverse

I have two code snippets . which one is better.

```
var texts:Array = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
texts.reverse();
for(var index:int=0; index < texts.length; index++) {
    trace(texts[index]);
}
```

Or

```
var texts:Array = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
for( var index:int = texts.length; --index;) {
      trace(texts[index]);
}
```

In former we have reverse operation and then print it and in latter we start from the length and start printing the array. The goal is to traverse the array from last.

Comment: 2nd one looks better than former.
The 1st one, `texts.length` is calculated for each iteration.
The 1st one, comparing `index` with `texts.length` for each iteration.
The 2nd one, `texts.length` is calculated once.

In addition, 2nd one is easier to read than 1st one.

[This article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/optimizing-flash-performance.html) also says that the reverse for loop is fastest.

Comment: @YasuyukiUno are you sure that texts.length is calculated per iteration? I am pretty sure that the length property is only updated when an item is added to the array.

Comment: @Zze I think for that.
`texts.length` is recalculated per iteration.
To avoid that, creating a variable outside the loop is better.
`var len:int = texts.length;
for(var index:int=0; index < len; index++)`

Comment: @YasuyukiUno It shouldn't be recalculated, because a proper list or array implementation would cache `length` internally. But still, it will be queried, this adds some code to access an object's property, call a getter, then pass the returned value backwards, this would make the first code slower, but it'll only matter with the array's length in millions, maybe not even thousands. But there's also a `reverse()` call which can be very costly, so if you don't really need the reversed array elsewhere, it's better to reverse-iterate anyway.

Comment: @Vesper, Zze  I just learned. Thank you.

Comment: @Vesper can you please verify the answer I have posted? Do you think the script I created is accurate?

Comment: "better" is a matter of opinion.  I like the first loop as it is more clear what you're doing.  The second loop has a cute trick to only need two statements in the `for` declaration, but that looks like an error at first glance.  OTOH, the second loop is faster by virtue of accessing the array fewer times (not that it matters for such a small dataset!).  Which one is better?  It depends.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script which evaluates time elapsed between for loops. After running the application numerous of times, it appears that the 2nd for loop is fastest.
Averaging: 4.168000000000001 | 4.163000000000002 seconds respectively for 100 iterations of each for loop.

The script is as follows:

import flash.events.Event;

```
var _t:int = getTimer();
var dt:Number;
var started:Boolean = false;
var iteration:int = 0;

var timer1:Number = 0;
var timer2:Number = 0;

var numberOfIterations = 100;

var texts1:Array = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
var texts2:Array = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
texts2.reverse();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, onExitFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    var t:int = getTimer();
    dt = (t - _t) * 0.001;
    _t = t;

    iteration++;
    // small FLA load buffer
    if(iteration == 50 && !started)
    {
        iteration = 0;
        started = true;
    }
}

function onExitFrame(e:Event):void {
    if(started)
    {
        if(iteration < numberOfIterations)
        {
            for(var index:int=0; index < texts1.length; index++) {}
            timer2 += dt;
            trace("Time Elapsed Alg 2: " + (timer2));
        }
        else
        {           
            for( var index:int = texts2.length; --index;) {}
            timer1 += dt;
            trace("Time Elapsed Alg 1: " + (timer1));
        }

        if(iteration == ((numberOfIterations*2)-1))
        {
            trace("________________________________________");
            trace("FINAL: " + timer1 + " | " + timer2);
            removeEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, onExitFrame);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

I am interested to see what others get using the following script, as it seems reliable on my PC as if I switch the for loop positions, the results still indicate that the fastest is:

```
var texts:Array = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
for( var index:int = texts.length; --index;) {
      trace(texts[index]);
}
```

Comment: You are measuring the wrong part of code. You should do like this: `getTimer()`, a for loop with ~10k iterations, `getTimer()`, get time difference. Instead you're measuring your SWF's framerate.

Comment: @Vesper That is what I had originally, however the results confused me, 10000 iterations for a value of 3 & 7 ? `var _int = 0;
trace(getTimer());
for(var index2:int=0; index2 < 100000; index2++) {_int++;}
trace(getTimer());`

Comment: `getTimer()` captures time from SWF start in milliseconds, to get how long did the code take you need to `var oldtime:int=getTimer(); code(); oldtime=getTimer()-oldtime; trace("Code took",oldtime,"ms.");`

Comment: @Vesper Going back to what I posted originally, how do you explain the difference in the recorded times then if I am only measuring the frame rate? And also how do you explain the numbers staying respective of where I place the for loops?

Comment: Please provide details of what did you do in the answer by editing it, I can't get what have you tried and what were the outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

The first one doesn't trace the last item in the array ie 1

The second one does.

So I say the second is better.

I'm curious though - what's the correct way to code the first one so that it traces all the items in the array?